# Landing page is not displaying in Reactjs /Express while starting the server.js file

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks

How can I display `home` as landing page. I don't know how to link the server.js to my landing page or should i link to App.js ? Now when I run the `node server.js` via command prompt, it is displaying as below. I have build my React components under components folder( *using react hooks*). Index.js file is under src/ folder

[image]

[image]

//Following is the server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

// create a GET route
app.get('/register', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ express: 'Connected Express backend to React' });
});
```

// I have added the index.html as suggested in the server.js

```
   app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + './public/index.html'));
});
```

//Following is my App.js file

```
import Register from './components/Register';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Aboutus from './components/Aboutus';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';

const App = () => {

  const componentDidMount = () => {
     //Call our fetch function below once the component mounts
    this.callBackendAPI()
    .then(res => this.setState({ data: res.express }))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
   route from server.js
    const callBackendAPI = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/express_backend');
    const body = await response.json();

    if (response.status !== 200) {
      throw Error(body.message)
    }
    return body;
  };
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Navigation />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
          <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/aboutus" component={Aboutus} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

//following is my http-common.js:

```
import axios from "axios";

const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  }
})

export default http;
```

// Following index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my previous answer due to the fact that now I understood what you are trying to achieve here. You shouldn't need any express app to display your react application since it's a one-page application. If you are tring to set up an express application to serve as the backend of your react app, it should be a whole new application in a different folder as the react aplication. Then you can connect both using a proxy on your react app. Finally both applications should be running for both frontend and backend to work. Here is a walkthrough to help you achieve what you are tring to achieve. Hope this helps you. https://medium.com/@maison.moa/setting-up-an-express-backend-server-for-create-react-app-bc7620b20a61